# When creating HTML emails, should we use html, head, body tags?

Tags: html, email, html-email

In my email views, I usually just do something like...

```
<dl>
   <dt>Name</dt>
   <dd>Value</dd>
</dl>
```

Should I be doing it like this?

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <dl>
       <dt>Name</dt>
       <dd>Value</dd>
    </dl>
  </body>
</html>
```

In other words, like I was marking up a standalone document?

I guess I can safely assume any web based email client will strip it out?

What is the right way?

Comment: For what it's worth, Thunderbird outputs the `html`, `head`, and `body` tags in its messages.

Answer (score 55):

The right way is to follow the HTML [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/). You can validate your HTML page [here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Your mail client should follow it and should throw away what's not supported or what's insecure, like JavaScript.

I'll expose some reasons why following standards could be beneficial here:

1. a webmail willing to show your mail as a full page, could keep your format.
2. a webmail will simply strip the tags and attributes it doesn't want. But you can never know which ones.
3. It's easier to find (server side) components that follow format standards, and thus are less error prone. Parsers not following standards could possibly break, making your email not getting shown.

Comment: -1 The right way is to test it in the relevant clients. While mail clients *should* follow the standards, virtually none of them do.

Comment: mschonaker is correct. If everybody starts following the standards, then the usage will be... well... standardized. Otherwise, all developers have to implement hacks for the flavor of the day (thinking of you, IE6!). The RIGHT way is to follow the standards.

Comment: There is no standard for "html emails". You're pointing to the standard for html.

Comment: I agree with this answer, while many clients render invalid html anyway the most reliable format that will render across most clients is to have valid html!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The mime type of the part or body will be text/html. Regardless of the context this type should be adhered to by standards whether it be a web browser or an email client. @cjcela has the right idea, if we all stuck supporting IE8 the web wouldn't evolve. If we don't stick to standards how is rendered HTML in mail to evolve? What you should do is stick to the standards, but recognise that things like stylesheets in `head`s may be ignored and have a graceful fallback.

Answer (score 34):

Whether or not you include the html/head/body tags is entirely irrelevant — they are always optional and will not affect the rendering of the document in any way.

What matters most is whether quirks mode is on or not. Unfortunately, you can’t control that in a webmail setting. Tables and inline styles are your friends. Your best bet is to test in as many webmail and desktop clients as you can.

Comment: [Which doctype should I use in HTML email?](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3317/correct-doctype-to-use-in-html-email/)

Comment: "they are always optional and will not affect the rendering of the document" thats simply not true, many renders are less fault tolerant and can quite rightly choose not to render the invalid html.

Comment: What happens when the mail client has a link "View this email in browser"? It'll be up to the default browser to render the invalid HTML.

Answer (score 18):

Many of the posts on this thread are rather old, and as a result they are no longer accurate.

These days HTML emails should include a doctype, html and body declaration if you intend to do anything fancy at all.

There are a multitude of guides on this subject which can help you learn how to properly code HTML Email, but most of them disregard the specifics of a doctype, which is how I stumbled on your question.

I suggest you read the following 2 posts which are from reputable teams familiar with the various problems:

[campaign monitor's take](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3317/correct-doctype-to-use-in-html-email/)

[email on acid's take](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/doctype_-_the_black_sheep_of_html_email_design/)

Comment: Funny... you say the posts here are old and you put a link in your answer to a blog post that's 7 years old!

Comment: I did, but the blog posts that were selected were carefully chosen due to their authoritative nature, and they were rather forward looking at the time. The opinions they expressed were fairly uncommon back then, especially when you contrast to the dated assertions that are shared by the other responses here.

Comment: @AlexisWilke and one of the links was even [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903200/when-creating-html-emails-should-we-use-html-head-body-tags/3903234#comment29800309_3903234) 3 years prior! But at least it's in an answer now so I can try to bump it up the list with an upvote

Answer (score 12):

Depends entirely on the email client that receives it.  In my experience, most email clients that will interpret HTML don't care if you have full body/head/html tags, etc.  In fact you don't even need those tags for most browsers.  You need to have the head tags to include style/title, etc.  Otherwise they are not really necessary, per se.  I've never seen them to be necessary.

Comment: The html/head/body tags are always optional.

Answer (score 11):

There's 1 thing I know to be true: Using HTML opening and closing tags will help in general spam scoring due to the fact that many such appliance based filters and software firewalls will add a point or so to an email that uses html but does not use the opening and closing tags.

Comment: Do you have some evidence to support this claim?

Comment: I observed this very behaviour within the past few days simply by "viewing original" in Gmail. There I could see a spam score for an email with no opening closing tags: e.g. X-Spam-Level: * |
X-Spam-Report: score=1.6 tests=HTML_MESSAGE, HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG, MIME_HTML_ONLY | X-Spam-Score: 1 - e.g. See http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG

Comment: I have seen this as well, and some companies have their threshold for spam quarantine so low that missing the HTML tags can be enough to prevent your email from getting through. This page doesn't list the exact settings available but I have seen the software leave a message about the rule "HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG," with the description" HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag."
https://techlib.barracuda.com/BSF/SpamScoring

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a right way but trying to make the email viewable in as many email readers as posible.

I usually check the emails in Thunderbird, because Outlook forgives more.

In Thunderbird this is the HTML code for an email (i have an extension that shows the html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
        This is the body text<br>
<div class="moz-signature"><i><br>
<br>
Regards<br>
Alex<br>
</i></div>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, i use plain text email for all my web forms every time I can. I had many issues with blackberry email using html+plain text emails.

Comment: I tried your email format and it just comes out the same way I typed it in javascript: eg:  var body = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">';  email received <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> .. .how do you make it "work" in javascript?