# PHP mail not displaying body, head tags

Tags: php, email, html-email

I know there are a lot of similar questions about html tags not displaying using `mail()`. I've read through a bunch of them to see if it mentioned my specific problem but I couldn't find anything.

My problem is not with HTML tags not rendering correctly, it's that the `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>` and `<body>` tags are missing completely. All the other tags get displayed correctly. I've done research and tested by changing the headers but I always get the same results. If I remove the headers the email displays all of the tags but in regular text. When I add the headers is when the 4 main tags disappear.

I'm not sure if it's a PHP thing or if it's an email client thing. On Gmail all of those 4 tags are gone, however on Yahoo I do get the `title` tag.

I checked to make sure `mail.add_x_header` is set and it is.

I'm working on a Joola website and Joomla provides a class to send emails as well. I tried using that first and I got the same results. That is why I tried using PHP's mail function.

Below is the code that I'm using. I got it from a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-send-email.php) site and I've tried changing the headers to different settings but I always get the same results.

```
$to = "test_1@yahoo.com";
$subject = "My HTML email test.";
$headers = "From: info@test.org\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@test.org\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: info@test.org\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<h1> This is a test </h1>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
   echo "The email has been sent!";
`enter code here`} else {
   echo "The email has failed!";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When creating HTML emails, should we use html, head, body tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903200/when-creating-html-emails-should-we-use-html-head-body-tags)

Comment: It's still kind of confusing. I kind of figured it might be the email clients but I've also created email templates before and I would include all of the HTML tags. That's why I wasn't completely sure. I would add style declarations in the head tag and the styles would appear. That's what I wanted to do in this case. The only difference now is that the email is being generated with PHP.
So I think what I'm understanding is HTML tags only display correctly if you use an email provider like MainChimp.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably as expected. Email clients try and display multiple emails, but instead of using tons of iframes or something like that, they parse the code and strip it down to the relevant parts.

So they will cut `<html>`; `<title>` makes no sense because the page has it's own page title (the email client page), unless they want to change the title for each email open, say; `<body>` will get transformed into a `<div>`, typically; and the `<head>` will get interpreted too.

Here's Gmail webmail's `<head>` section on a random email:

```
<div id=":csl" class="a3s aXjCH "><u></u>

  
  <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><!-- This is my <body> -->
```

And the same on Yahoo:

```
<div data-test-id="message-body-container"><div data-test-id="message-view-body" class="I_52qC D_FY W_6D6F"><div class="X_6MGW"></div><div class="msg-body P_wpofO mq_AS" data-test-id="message-view-body-content"><div class="jb_0 X_6MGW N_6Fd5"><div><div id="yiv8851120227">

    <title></title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
... <!--lots of styles here -->
</style>
  
  <div> <!--Used to be <body> -->
```

And Gmail App on Android allowed a few more things:

```
<html><head>
  <meta id="meta-viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=2" data-zoom-on="maximum-scale=2" data-zoom-off="user-scalable=no">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mobile-webview.gmail.com/android_asset/conv.css">
  
  <style>  .spacer{display: none !important }
    img[blocked-src] { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; }
  </style>
  <style>  .spacer{display: none !important }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0 16px;"><!--This was inserted-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var JS_TOKEN = 'TSONS4YTXAF2U436RLHPASX5HN3JIU3O';
    window.ConversationView.createTracingInstant(JS_TOKEN, "BODY_PARSE_STARTED");
</script>
<div id="conversation-header" class="spacer" style="height: 116px;"></div>
<div id="conversation-promotion" class="spacer" style="height: 0px;"></div>
<div id="m#msg-f:1671067648779872745" class="mail-message expanded">
    <div class="mail-message-header spacer" style="height: 80px;"></div>
    <div class="mail-message-content collapsible zoom-normal mail-show-images " style="display: block; margin: 16px 0; user-select: auto; -webkit-user-select: auto;"><div class="clear"><u></u>
...
  <div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;min-width:100%;background-color:#ffffff"> <!--Used to be <body>-->
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I kind of figure it might be the case. The reason I wasn't entirely sure is because I've used email providers before. And I've created templates where I added style sheets in the head tag and everything got rendered. This is actually what I wanted to do in this case only instead of an email provider I was intending to use PHP.

I guess I got my answer. Once again, thank you.

Comment: <style> has good support across mobile email clients; it won't work on many desktops/webmail. Therefore we adopt a "desktop-first" approach rather than mobile-first, because we can use <style> to make it responsive for mobiles, but not the other way around. https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-style/

Comment: Just a nuance for future readers, that we can actually make emails mobile-first, and most desktops do in fact support at least some `<style>` tags including `@media min-width`. I prefer mobile-first these days as supporting Gmail IMAP accounts (which is basically the only mobile client that doesn't support `<style>` blocks) is more of a priority than supporting rarely used desktops. More work involved though, e.g. catering for Outlook desktop.